# Using Date with GetPivotData

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a pivot table that I am trying to reference using a date as part of the lookup. The pivot table data can be grouped by day, week or month (there is a little VBA that controls this) However, I cannot seem to create a GETPIVOTDATA function that will work with all three groupings.
 - When grouped by day, GETPIVOTDATA seems to want the day of the year (1-365), it won't accept a date.

```
    =GETTPIVOTDATA(value, pt, "Date", 184)
```

- When grouped by week, it will accept a date and return the week that the date falls in

```
    =GETTPIVOTDATA(value, pt, "Date", Date(2012, 08, 22))
```

- When grouped by month, it seems to want the month of the year (1-12)

```
    =GETTPIVOTDATA(value, pt, "Date", 11)
```

Is there anyway to use a date with all three groupings? Bear in mind that the groupings will change but the formula won't so the same formula has to work with any grouping.

The alternatives are using an IF statement and date manipulation or using VBA whenever I change the groupings. However, I feel that the should be a way to just use the date, regardless of the grouping.

Comment: I would do as you suggested with an IF statement, however, but the statement in a separate cell that gives you the format you need based on the grouping, then reference that cell as the last argument in your  GETPIVOTDATA formula.

Comment: Personally, I've used the CHOOSE statement over an IF to solve this problem. I have a set of Radio Buttons that select the date period with VBA to change the pivot table. The CHOOSE statement uses the output value from the radio buttons to slot the correct format into the GETPIVOTDATA statement.